# Is there a criteria in the design of a cognitive control task (Flanker task with letters H and S)?

Tags: error-related-negativity

In this task, there are 4 trial types : congruent (HHHHHHH, SSSSSSS), incongruent (SSSHSSS, HHHSHHH). In order to collect enough ERN (error-related negativity), a component elicited after an error, subjects have to make enough error in the trials. I have seen ERP studies using this task, but the trial numbers vary from 300 to 700 (Lorist, 2011; Steinhauser, 2011), some with 1/3 congruent, others with 1/2, so I wonder is there a criteria in regard to:

1.the percentage of congruent and incongruent trials

2.at least how many trials in order to have an error rate of 20% (if 100 trials takes 10 minutes to complete)

How about in a stroop task?

1. Steinhauser, M., & Kiesel, A. (2011). Performance monitoring and the causal attribution of errors. Cognitive, Affective, & Behavioral Neuroscience, 11(3), 309-320.
2. Lorist, M. M., Boksem, M. A., & Ridderinkhof, K. R. (2005). Impaired cognitive control and reduced cingulate activity during mental fatigue. Cognitive Brain Research, 24(2), 199-205.

Comment: Answer from my professor: Depends on what data one is collecting and the error rate, there isn't a criteria in the design of this type cognitive control task.